# How to load all resources from one WPF application to another WPF application by giving the COM reference to .dll file

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have two WPF applications. One is a parent application and second one is a child application. I want to render a WPF window from the second application into first application, on a mouse click event.

I am able to do it, but the problems are: the first application does not load all the resources that the second application has. Because of this, the first WPF application is throwing an exception while calling methods or events.

I want load all resources like styles, trigger events by giving a `.dll` reference only.

Any suggestions to if there are other possible ways to render one WPF application to another one.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any relation to COM?

Comment: I don't get it. If it's another app, it isn't required to look the same as first app. If it does, then your styles should be in a separate Theme project, and have some kind of standard for all projects in your app to load current theme used in the app.